# Fuzzy name matching using big data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file that contains approximately 150k rows of data and a script that attempts to match any instances where a company's names is spelled differently. The basic logic behind the script is that there is a list of names the for loop iterates through and checks against a master list of names. The following order is the sequence in which the function evaluates each name in the list in order to create a new list of vendor names that will be appended to the dataframe as a column:

1. If the company name is in the master list of names, it doesnt need to be changed, therefore, append it to the list that will be inserted into the dataframe as a column
2. If the match ratio is less than a predetermined threshold and the company name is not already in the list of master names, append the company name to both the list that will be inserted into the dataframe and the list of master names
3. Compare the first strings of characters to validate if the company name and matched name from the master list

   - This is to prevent false positive where company names such as "DJ Manufacturing" and "LCR Manufacturing" will return a high ratio, but are not the same company
   - If the secondary comparison returns a high match ratio, append the company name to the list that will be added to the dataframe

The code I wrote works, but is painfully slow. I am a financial analyst and use python to automate certain tasks, but have very little coding education, so any feedback on how I could make the code more efficient would be greatly appreciated!

```
def clean_names(list, col, master_name_list, low_threshold, high_threshold):
int1 = 0
new_name_col = []
for comp in list:
    int1 += 1
    print('Cleaning ' + col + ' data: '+ str(int1) + '/' + str(len(list)) + ' rows completed', end = "\r")
    if int1 == len(list): print()
    #####   Extract list of strings matched in the master vendor list to the company name evaluated
    comp_text = process.extract(comp, master_name_list, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio)
    #####   Begin for loop that iterates through the list of matched strings
    for matched_name, fz_ratio in comp_text:
        #####   If the matched name is in the master vendor list already, append the name to the list of data that will be appended to the dataframe as a new column
        if comp in master_name_list:
            new_name_col.append(comp)
            break
        else:
            #####   If ratio is less than the threshold limit and the company name is not in the master list, append the name to the list of data that will be appended
            #####   to the dataframe as a column as well as the master name list for comparison in the next iteration
            if fz_ratio < low_threshold and comp not in master_name_list:
                master_name_list.append(comp)
                new_name_col.append(comp)
                break
            else:
                #####   Check to see if first string of characters is the same in the matched pairs
                #####   This is to account for false positives where company names such as "DJ Manufacturing" and "LCR Manufacturing" will return a high ratio, but are
                #####   not the same company
                test = fuzz.token_set_ratio(comp.split(' ', 1)[0], matched_name.split(' ', 1)[0])
                if test >= high_threshold and comp not in master_name_list:
                    new_name_col.append(matched_name)
                    break
                else:
                    master_name_list.append(comp)
                    new_name_col.append(comp)
                    break
return new_name_col
```

Comment: I think this question may be more likely to get help on Code Review, since your code works as expected but you're looking for improvements for efficiency: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you provide any more details on where the bottlenecks are in terms of speed?  What parts are taking a long time do you think?  Also is there any sample data you can provide?

Comment: @dspencer thank you for the feedback, I will definitely go there for some further clarification

Comment: @jawsem Yes, the data we are processing is the public controller dataset contained within the MSHA database. I was able to go through the code and remove certain redundancies to the point at which it is now running twice as fast... but its still taking a considerable amount of time to run